# What does 뜨겁게 mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I'm trying to learn Korean using series titles, so excuse my ignorant question
here is the Title:

**일단 뜨겁게 청소하라**

The translation of 뜨겁게 is hot which it doesn't make sense to me, I think it means passionately based on the English title, but I hope you can explain briefly if this word is a combination, and if there some grammar behind it.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm Korean but never heard "뜨겁게" using like that. I can kinda understand, but it feels awkward to me.

Comment: Thank you, its great when you get insight from a native. so it look like its not a good word to memorize.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I misdirected you. It is a good word to memorize since it is used a lot, such as '뜨거운 성원(enthusiastic support)'. I think I felt awkward because it is not used with `청소`(cleaning) in most case.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. what about meaning 'passionately'. it is often used?

Comment: I'm not professional, so don't quote me on this. But it can be used for that meaning. I searched Naver dictionary and one of the meaning was `(Figuratively) emotions or passions are intense.` I'm not sure how frequent it used.

Comment: I'm not interested in professional usage, all i care about is popular common words used in everyday conversations between Korean people. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

뜨겁다 can be meant "hot" or "full of energy/passion".

So, the sentence means "firstly, clean passionately".

Answer (score 3):

### Derived meaning: passionately.

It *is* the word you know, “뜨겁다 (hot).” You've just stumbled upon another sense of the word that is slightly rhetoric: *passionately enthusiastic, eager, or excited.* It's been derived from the basic sense of the word: *having a high degree of heat or a high temperature*.

#### Usage note

It's more of a word that is used in catchphrases/quotes rather than usual conversations, as is a slightly rhetoric, literary way of expression. Often used in imperative sentences.

And an extra note: considering the usage described above, “뜨겁게 청소하라” sounds a bit weird; why would someone say

> “Sweep it all up, with passion.”  <sub>- Somebody in the world</sub>

?

---

### Or, might be a mistranslation.

It might be a casual, quick, and nonstandard way of saying “뜨거운 물로 청소하라. (Clean it up with hot water.).”

**EDIT**: turned out this is not the case! See comments below.

Comment: 일단 뜨겁게 청소하라 is a title of Korean drama.

Comment: @HKLee Oh, that's a good context to know. In that case, the former would be the right one and is pretty much intended to sound bizarre yet intriguing.

Answer (score 2):

뜨겁게 = passionately

There are another examples of same usage : 뜨겁게 기도하라 (pray) 뜨겁게 사랑하라 (love)

뜨겁게 contains meanings of enough(충분히) or wholeheartedly (정성스럽게)